# REST или Servlet

Tags: java, servlet, rest

Задача: Написать форму авторизации, на которую будет перекидывать пользователя при переходе на определённый урл. Те много сервисов будут использоваться одну форму авторизации. Стоит ли в этой ситуации использовать rest и какие у него преимущества перед обычными сервлетами?

Comment: По моему вы путаете теплое с мягким, REST - это архитектура, Servlet - это интерфейс в Java, который используется для реализации взаимодействия с клиентов.

Comment: Проще говоря, перечитав несколько статей я так и не понял, для чего именно мне нужен REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSO - это сложно и там тысячи нюансов, которые надо знать и уметь правильно решить в коде. При этом авторизация и аутентификация по своей природе очень сложны в реализации, т.к. пронизывают зачастую все уровни реализации и это вообще специфичная тема.

Я предлагаю всегда брать готовые решения, которые вас избавят от хождения по граблям - Apache Shiro, даже если они `чуть (тут сложно сформулировать, сколько это чуть)` оверкил.

REST это архитектура, которая может быть имплементирована в том числе и на сервлетах. В спецификацию REST входит много принципов и т.п. (JSR 311 & JSR 339). Есть специальные REST фреймворки (например [Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)), которые упрощают создание REST сервисов.

По большому счету, REST - публичный интерфейс вашего сервиса, что бы его можно было использовать из других сервисов (безопасно, надежно, масштабируемо).
Захотели и сделали простенькую HTML страничку с формами или jsp страницу, или javascript ajax, или php приложение хочет узнать, что разрешено этому пользователю.

Если не следовать требованиям этой архитектуры, то можно получить на выходе не отдельный сервис авторизации-аутентификации, а жуткую мешанину из своих сервисов, которые потом будут не разделимы. Такие системы могут быть очень дороги в поддержке, а уж про расширение или полную замену - я молчу.

Comment: К сожалению, нас в компании 2 джуна (больше разрабов нет), а задача реализовать поставлена

Comment: Подскажите, а почему нельзя использовать обычные сервлеты для создания такой аутентификации? Компания занимается информационной безопасностью.

Comment: У нас уже реализована авторизация/аутентификация (в обычном виде) в соответствии со всеми стандартами информационной безопасности. Как я понимаю работать это будет следующим образом: Переходим на нужный нам сервер - этот сервер пишет нам что-то в куки - затем отправляет нас на сервис где происходит авторизация/аутентификация - этот сервис пишет нам что-то в куки и подписывается - мы возвращаемся на наш сервер, показываем, что у нас в куках и если всё ок попадаем внутрь. Для чего для всего этого отдельная библиотека? В чём сложность в реализации? Огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Тогда это меняет все дело, у вас уже готов бэкенд для всего и вам нужно только его использовать в своей форме (сервелете)? Я правильно понял? И у этого сервиса авторизации есть РЕСТ интерфейс?

Comment: Авторизацию/аутентификацию писали мы (джуны), пока что она не готова к использованию, как SSO, но нам объяснят как это сделать, и скорее всего всё получится. Рест интерфейса нет, я не до конца понимаю в чём его суть и какие преимущества, хотя несколько статей на эту тему прочитал. Не могли бы объяснить, пожалуйста?

Comment: Грубо говоря ты пишешь джава класс который будет принимать запросы по определенному url(api/user/) например. И клиент будет посылать по одному url разные запросы (get, post, put, delete) в зависимости от типа запроса будет выполняться соответствующий метод

Comment: По поводу авторизации лучше использовать spring security. Сложного там нет ничего. Если будут вопросы я смогу подсказать

Comment: Посмотрите на пример от [атласиан](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication). Вам нужно будет разные сервисы завязать на эту авторизацию, они могут быть на разных языках и бежать на разных серверах. Как вы планируете наладить общение их с вашим сервисом авторизации? Проще всего сделать единый интерфейс - REST API.

Comment: MrGarison, а разве не тем же самым занимаются сервлеты?

Comment: Дополнил свой основной ответ. Вопрос сам по себе очень объемный, на него тяжело дать простой и однозначный ответ, не зная контекста проекта. Я сам еще тот говнокодер, так что все выше сказаное - это имхо )